# Average Loop Length For N Singly Connected Nodes

Tags: graph-theory

Given N nodes where each node links to a single node randomly (links to self are ok, each node has 1 and only 1 node linking to it) what is the average loop length?

Example: If you have 100 nodes the odds are very small that you'll have a single chain of length 100. The odds are also very small that you'll have 100 nodes, each linking to itself. So what is the average loop length? Is it sqrt(N)?

Answer (score 0):

Well I went ahead and wrote a small program to simulate the situation by randomly shuffling node links and then counting the loop lengths and maintaining a histogram. What appears is obviously an exponential function (k*e^(1-looplength)) where the highest probability is a loop length of 1 (node links to itself), then the next highest probability is a loop length of 2, then 3, then 4... where the probability is decreased by a constant ratio.

I'll leave a formal proof to someone else. Here's the meat of the program:

`#define MAXN 1000000
int nsize = 512;
unsigned long counts[MAXN] ={0};
void netcount(void)
{
    int *buf = malloc(nsize * sizeof(int));
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0;i<nsize;++i)
        buf[i] = i;
    for(i=0;i<nsize-1;++i)
    {
        j = i + rand() % (nsize - i);
        k = buf[i];
        buf[i] = buf[j];
        buf[j] = k;
    }
    for(i=0;i<nsize;++i)
    {
        j = 0;
        k = i;
        while(buf[k]>=0)
        {
            ++j;
            int t = buf[k];
                buf[k] = -1;
            k = t;
        }
        if(j) ++counts[j];
    }
    free(buf);
}`